# What risks should I consider when offered a daily based job offer in foreign country (Japan)

Tags: career-development, new-job, job-change

I am currently being contacted on LinkedIn for a potential job in Japan, but the contractor told me they would pay me on daily basis. I am not sure that accepting a position like this in a foreign country like Japan is a wise move.

What risks should I consider when considering accepting this position?

Comment: what does the recruiter mean by daily basis?  That you are evaluated and they choose wether to bring you back the next day, every day?

Comment: Would you even qualify for healthcare if you're paid on a daily basis? I don't know about Japan, but normally you can't pay foreigners on work visas that way.

Comment: Is this remote job offer ?

Answer (score 6):

Seems **very risky** to me. There are many hidden traps on that road.

- Who pays relocation expenses? What benefits are included?
- How reliable is your income? Is it "occasional days", or "day after day with no breaks"?

You want to avoid situation where you paid for relocation, and you don't have steady income to rely on.

I hope I would never be in so desperate situation I would have to even consider such risky offer. Or vice versa, I hope the offer you have is **so lucrative** that taking such huge risk makes sense. Your situation may vary, and only you know if it is worth for you.

Offer might make sense for someone already located in Japan and lacking full time job, but otherwise? No thanks.

**Edit:** One more thing: unless you are very **interested in relocating to Japan** (which is not obvious from your question) and your skills are in such demand what you would be able to find another position very quickly, I would not consider relocating into country (with all the **language and cultural barriers**). **and more**: in contract, I would like to **have a clause that if job will be cancelled** in certain time (say under 6 months), I would want to receive **severance pay** which will allow me to relocate back. In writing.

Summary: thanks but no thanks for such offer. Japan if interesting country, but this is NOT interesting offer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too, i Have asked them to give me the details but can't risk my steady career like this. Haven't heard from the guy yet.

Comment: I haven't heard from that HR person from the company after asking basic questions.

Comment: Likely you were lucky to avoid complicated mess. If they could not answer basic question, they are likely hunting for a more trusting mark.

Answer (score 3):

That...sounds incredibly risky.

- What happens if you go over (or are even relocated), you are there for three
  months, but there's only ten days' worth of work?

  - What's the visa issue? Who handles that cost?
  - Are basic living expenses handled as part of your renumeration, or are you expected to handle all of that?
  - If you're supposed to handle everything...do you know how much rent/food/transportation would cost for a month, and are you prepared to handle that?
  - What happens if you get over there, you do two months' worth of work at a 40-hour work week...but then the project evaporates? Are you left to fend for yourself and try and find a job, or left to foot your own bill for relocating back?

Is there a possibility for you to work this job remotely (assuming that it's programming, development, design, content management/generation) for a while, on a trial basis, to see how things work out - and then reconsider the "relocate" question, based on how much work you're given / how much you're paid?

Without knowing more of the details, I'd say that this offer has 'risk' written all over it. If this person hasn't provided you with more details, I'd say that's a place to start asking questions.